# caching previous' page jquery instead of current one

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, caching

I'm importing an external js file right after the opening body

```
<body>
   <script src="http://website.com/jsfile#1"></script>
   etc...
</body>
```

the head includes the following:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.css" /><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

the script file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', ".clickable", function() {
        var o_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#l_id').val(o_id); 
        $("#pick_location").attr("action", "pick_contact.php?l_id=" + o_id + "&p_id=" + $('#p_id').attr('value') + "&f_id=" + $('#f_id').attr('value'));
        $('#pick_location').submit();
    });
});
```

later I dynamically created clickable divs that trigger the script, e.g.

```
<?php
    echo '<div id ="'.$id.'" class="clickable"><div>test</div></div>';
?>
```

clicking submits the form and it takes the user to another page very similar again where the user can pretty much do exactly the same thing (the application has to do with selecting stuff in one page, then more stuff in next, etc) as before but with a different script

```
<script src="jsfile#2"></script>
```

the problem I'm having is that in that second page the clicked div is triggering the js file jsfile#1 instead of the jsfile#2. So, this caching is giving me a headache. Same results in latest Chrome and Firefox. Can't seem to find anything that works for my problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: # is reserved for anchors, so your two src URLs are actually the same.

Comment: that was a name simplification to make it easy to explain, these are two actual names: pick_location_v2.js and pick_contact_v2.js